# How to redirect Dynamic urls of home pages to Static Home page url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site has too many dynamic urls of home page.

Like this:

```
example.com/wp/?84677=4f5nh664
example.com/wp/?84677=4f5nh665
example.com/wp/?84677=4f5mh666
```

I want to redirect all of them to my static home page i.e.

```
example.com/wp
```

How to do this using htaccess file.

---

update:

Solved:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^84677=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^wp/$ http://example.com/wp/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp/\?84677=.+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,R]
```

Comment: it is still showing ?84677=4f5nh664 in the end of the url

Comment: Im testing it right now. coming back with the results

Comment: Hi see my updated  answer it is working. @starkeen was right just missed the rewrite base

Comment: updated code in my question was started working. But now it's not working. I tried yours updated answers but it also not working for me.

I just a new problem in site. This "?84677=4f5nh664" thing is every where in my site. All the main and sub urls are ending with "?id=1" this thing. "id" remains the same "id number" keeps changes

Comment: I did not understand. Explain to me better your problem. Did you changed some links?

Comment: Try adding a base tag please in all your pages see my updated answer

Comment: I have posted another question about it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441139/how-to-redirect-dynamic-urls-to-their-relevant-static-urls-in-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment62384886_37441139

please see this question. I have simplify it there

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp/\?84677=.+
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,R]
```

Comment: browser saying example.com page isn’t working
example.com redirected you too many times.