# How to redirect dynamic urls to their relevant static urls in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Dynamic urls are like

```
example.com/wp/?2323e=467467
example.com/any-page.html?2323e=567856
example.com/any-folder/other-page.html?2323e=6435346
```

I want to redirect them all to their static urls like

```
example.com/wp/
example.com/any-page.html
example.com/any-folder/other-page.html
```

please suggest how to do this using 301 redirect

Comment: you don't need redirect. Now already the target pages are called

Comment: but in webmasters they are listed in Soft 404 errors

Comment: `example.com/any-page.html?2323e=567856` the same as `example.com/any-page.html` with query string `?2323e=567856`

Comment: Yes I understand that. But what to do with this soft404 which occurring because of this.

Answer (score 0):

To remove query strings, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

This will redirect :

```
/foo?querystring
```

to

```
/foo
```